# Dynamically allocated char pointer in main doesn't return string when using call by reference

Tags: c

I am trying to pass address of char pointer to a function by using call by reference. When I try to check the address of char pointer in main and function they both are different, why?. One more surprising thing what I cant understand is when using call by reference the string updated in function should actually reflect  in main also.

```
void fun(char *str){
    str = "hello";
    printf(" str address in fun is = %p\n",str);
    printf("In fun str is = %s\n",str);
}
int main(){
    char *str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(10));
    fun(str);
    printf(" str address is = %p\n",str);
    printf("In main str is = %s\n",str);
}
```

Output of the program is as follows:

```
str address in fun is = 0x804859b
In fun str is = hello
str address is = 0x839e008
In main str is =
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Can any one explain what actually is happening in this code. Why I am not able to get the string updated in main from function.
[Note: When I try the same code using int pointer this works fine. I am trying to understand the heap memory role in char pointer scenarios.]

Comment: `str = "hello";` should be `strcpy(str, "hello");`

Comment: You're not passing the pointer variable by reference. You're passing it by value. When you use a pointer to an `int`, don't you use the address-of operator to pass a pointer to the `int` variable? And use dereference in the function when doing the assignment? Think about that for a while.

Comment: Also, C doesn't really *have* "pass by reference", it only have pass by value. Pass by reference can be *emulated* by using pointers *to the variables*.

Comment: Your code for `fun` was written as if `str` was passed by reference. But it wasn't, it was passed by value. C doesn't have pass by reference, only C++ does. Changing the value of `str` in `fun` has no effect on anything outside of `fun` because this is C and all parameters are passed by value.

Comment: Finally, note that `malloc(sizeof(10))` doesn't allocate ten bytes, it allocates `sizeof(int)` bytes, usually four.

Comment: Then while using int in this code I can observe the same address for pointer variable in function as well in main, why is this so if call by reference is not there in C.

Comment: It seems that you expect `str = "hello";` to assign the string `hello` to `str`. That is not how strings work in C. Instead of setting `str` to `hello`, the code change the value of (the pointer) `str`. So `str` inside the function no longer points to the memory allocated in `main`. In C you need `strcpy` to assign (aka copy) the value of one string to another string.

Comment: @harish `... I can observe the same address for pointer variable....` Are you sure about that? How do you observe the **address**?

Comment: I tried checking using this code.

int main()
{
int *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
fun(p);
printf("p value is %p \n",p);
printf("*p value is %d \n",*p);
}
fun(int *p)
{
printf("fun - p value is %p \n",p);
printf("fun - *p value is %d \n",*p);
*p = 10;
printf("fun p value is %p \n",p);
printf("fun *p value is %d \n",*p);
}

Comment: @harish - The code you posted in the comment does **not** print the **address** of the variable `p`. It prints the value of `p`. And the value is the same because C uses pass-by-value.To print the **address** you need: `printf("Address of p is %p \n", (void*)&p); `

Comment: @4386427 - I mean I am printing address allocated by malloc not the address of pointer.

Comment: @harish - ok, that's another thing than **address of pointer variable**. Anyway try this: `void fun(char *str){ printf("value of str is %p \n",(void*)str); str = "hello"; printf("value of str is %p \n",(void*)str);....` Then you can easily see how you change the **value** of `str` instead of changing the contents of the memory pointed to be `str`

Comment: @harish Yes, the address, which you passed by *value*. So changing that value will have no affect on the caller.

Answer (score 5):

> I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Since pointers are also passed by value, this line

```
str = "hello";
```

*overwrites* the value passed from `main` to another value, namely, that of the location of `"hello"` string literal, for the duration of `fun` function call. That is why you see correct printouts inside `fun`. However, this re-assignment is not visible in `main`.

Replacing this line with

```
strcpy(str, "hello");
```

will fix the problem. Now both addresses and both string values will be the same.

**Note:** The allocation `char *str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(10));` is incorrect: you don't need `sizeof` in there. It should be `char *str = malloc(10);`

Comment: An easy way to see this is to add another |printf(" str address in fun is = %p\n",str);| before you assign |str = "hello";|. You will see it matches the address from main.

Comment: Note that the `strcpy` call will write beyond the bounds of what is allocated, the OP doesn't allocate ten bytes. So while it "fixes" the problem asked about, it introduces others and more subtle problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right, I completely missed the incorrect use of `sizeof`!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the working program with `int` looks something like this (simplified):

```
void fun(int *ptr)
{
    *ptr = 10;
}

int main(void)
{
    int var;
    fun(&var);
}
```

This is *emulating* pass by reference by passing a pointer ***to the variable*** and using the dereference operator in the function to access what the pointer `ptr` is pointing to.

In `fun` you have something like this

```
+-----+      +--------------------------+
| ptr | ---> | var in the main function |
+-----+      +--------------------------+
```

That is, `ptr` is pointing to the `var` variable in the `main` function. By using the dereference on `ptr` we can modify what `ptr` is pointing to, which as said is the `var` variable.

---

Now lets take a simplified version of the program you have problems with:

```
void fun(char *ptr)
{
    // 1
    ptr = "hello"
    // 2
}

void main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    fun(str);
}
```

At point `1` in the function above, `ptr` is pointing to the first element in the array `str` from the `main` function.

At point `2` (after the assignment) then `ptr` is pointing to the string literal `"hello"` instead. And as `ptr` is a local variable who will go out of scope once the function returns, the assignment is lost.

To fix this either you `strcpy` as [answered by dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42884076/440558). ***Or*** you can emulate pass by reference by passing a pointer *to the variable*:

```
void fun(char **ptr_to_ptr)
{
    // Note the use of the dereference operator here
    *ptr_to_ptr = "hello";
}

void main(void)
{
    char str[10] = "foobar";
    char *ptr = str;  // Make ptr point to the first element of str

    // Note the use of the address-of operator
    fun(&ptr);

    printf("%s\n", ptr);  // Will print "hello"
    printf("%s\n", str);  // Will print "foobar"
}
```

What the above program is doing is to change what `ptr` in the `main` function is pointing at.

***Important note:*** If you use dynamic allocation for `ptr` (like you do in your program) then `fun` as shown above will lead to a *memory leak*, because you no longer have the original pointer returned by `malloc`.